# Templated Class - Force compilation error on not supported class

Tags: c++, templates, cross-platform

I am using C++03 (cross platform) with only the standard libraries and I have a templated class that I want to fail on compile in case a non supported class is given.
So far I have a run time error generated:

```
template <class Key, class Val>
class MyClass: public other_class<Key, Val>
{
public:

    template<class T1M, class T2M>
    struct ThisGetter
    {
        static T1M Get()
        { 
            throw(std::exception("Failed")); //Change this to compilation failure
        }
    };

    template<class T2M>
    struct ThisGetter<int, T2M>
    {
        static Key Get()
        {
            int temp = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
            return temp;
        }
    };
};
```

I want, if possible, to have the following:

```
MyClass<int, int> works; // compilation successful
MyClass<string, int> fails; // compilation failed
```

Is it possible? Removing the first ThisGetter cant be done if I understand correctly

Thanks

Comment: `static_assert(false)`?

Comment: @PavelGolubev Not for pre c++11 standard.

Comment: It is c++11 and i dont use boost

Comment: In a pre-C++11 system and without sing Boost (why?), make your own type-traits to handle it? Or use specialization?

Comment: sorry but I don't understand: you want a C++03 or a C++11 solution? And you want exclude a black list of unsupported classes (and accept any other class) or you want accept only a limited white list of classes?

Comment: C++03 as I mentioned in the main post. The goal is excluding classes that weren't accepted - accepting a white list.
I will probably use the boost static assert option unless another nice idea is suggested :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've eventually added the boost option. The problem is that it doesn't accept the boost static assert(false) when compiling on mac/centos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few problems with boost I decided to remove it. (errors on centos7 for some reason but it worked on centos6/win/mac)
I've use the following method, declaring:

```
template<bool> struct MyStaticAssert;
template<> struct MyStaticAssert<true> {};
```

and in the unwanted function:

```
foo()
{
    MyStaticAssert<false>()
}
```

starting to like templates :)